# JwtSecurityTokenHandler InboundAlgorithmMap in ASP.Net 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am upgrading to RC1 of Asp.Net 5, and had existing code which had mappings for the InboundAlgorithmMap.  This doesn't appear to be a static property of this class in RC1.  Did it get moved or did it get removed?  What is the proper way to handle these mappings going forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been removed but *may* be re-introduced before RTM: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/316.

To work around this new limitation, you can consider creating your own signature provider, to handle the algorithm conversion before invoking the default one.

Comment: That is what I did to get over the hurdle, but wanted to make sure it hadn't simply been removed.